# Reliability sending and receiving email (mainly about receiving)

Tags: email

I currently have a ‘forwards to’ set up in my godaddy account, so email sent to richard@richardclunan.com goes to my gmail.

And I send email from my gmail so it looks like it’s sent from richard@richardclunan.com

My godaddy account is using a POP server.

I’m wondering about the reliability. It’s not an issue for me if some emails are delayed sometimes. But it is an issue if I don’t receive emails or if emails I send out don’t get to their destinations.

Is this an issue with a POP server?

I’m guessing any issue would be with me receiving email, rather than sending – since they’re sent from gmail, but received via a godaddy POP server.

– I have my domains registered with godaddy, hosting on hostgator, and using POP email server on godaddy. I could use the hostgator email server if that might be a better set up; though I don’t want to change it unnecessarily.

– Or I guess another option would be to use a Google Apps for business account, instead of my free gmail – would this mean better reliability? Would doing this mean I’d then not be using the godaddy POP server, or would I still be using a mail server at godaddy, since my domain is registered with godaddy?

Thanks.

Comment: To avoid further disappointment please read our rules and faq before posting.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the question there. The questions are different. The question here is more about RECEIVING email and it is about POP servers.

Comment: Can this question be reopened?

Comment: Sorry but if the question is more about receiving emails from customers with a forwarder that is not sent through your website then this wouldn't fall under a webmaster question. If your referring to receiving emails that are sent from your website then forwarded then  delivery success rate is improved using the linked post. Furthermore the question is opinionated as you are asking if you should use Google Apps or GoDaddy since both are valid solutions this part of the question is purely opinionated which is not allowed again, which again if you read our FAQ and Rules it mentions this.

Comment: Finally if you prefer you could always use our chat channel where such rules are not enforced.